Why will a positive stagger increase biplane efficiency, while a negative stagger will decrease efficiency?
On a biplane, why will a positive stagger (top wing more forward relative to the bottom one) be more efficient than a negative stagger? In both cases the wing’s pressure fields are more separate, so why does it matter if it’s positive or negative stagger?
In other words, why will a negative stagger decrease efficiency while a positive stagger will increase efficiency?
What is the difference?

Note: I have read the answers to this question, and this question actually was sparked by one of those answers. It explained that positive stagger will increase efficiency and that negative stagger will decrease efficiency, but it didn’t explain why, which is what this question is asking.

Does this answer your question? Why do most biplanes have their top wing slightly forward of the lower wing?

@sophit: Actually, I think this question derives from one of the answers to that question. It uses the same image. The linked PDF makes the claim that negative stagger reduces lift and efficiency without explanation.

@FredLarson That is exactly correct.

@sophit FredLarsons assumption is correct. The answer(s) you linked actually sparked this question.

(Also if anyone has a vote to close and you see why this isn’t a duplicate, I’d appreciate it to be removed so this doesn’t get closed, thanks)

While not an answer, you can just look at the picture and see some of the answer. Wings deflect air above them more than below them. The bottom wing will influence the air stream of the top wing. Moving the top wing forward compared to the bottom wing will put the top wing in "clean" air. Moving it backwards puts it further into the disruption caused by the bottom wing. This may help: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27441/how-far-away-from-a-wings-surface-does-the-air-stream-remain-unaffected

With negative stagger, perhaps the lower wing makes a shadow on air flow to wing above, reducing efficiency?
A bit as 'Super Stall' in F-104 and other T tail machines. A wind tunnel test could provide clues.
Blessings +

With advanced lower wing, it can make 'Shadow' on upper wing, reducing efficiency, more possible as AoA increases. A bit as Super Stall in F-104 and other T-tail machines. To be confirmed in wind tunnel. Or not?

Because we look only at efficiency at positive lift.
Remember that increasing the distance between the wings of a biplane increases efficiency (see for example Table III in Max Munk's NACA report 151). And now consider what the air "sees" as it approaches the staggered biplane at a positive angle: Positive stagger will make the distance between the wings appear larger and vice versa.
To illustrate my point I have made 3D of two wings in Tinkercad:

First the side view. Span is 8.6 meters, distance is 1 meter, stagger is also 1 meter.

Now the view from the front at a positive angle.

and lastly the same at a negative angle. Notice how the two wings seem to move closer together.
That is all! Aerodynamically, the distance, and, consequently, the interference, between the wings changes with the sine of the angle of attack and proportional to stagger.

I see, thanks for your answer. So is David's comment on my question also correct? In that the upper surface deflects more air, so it has more of an influence on the air above than below?

Brilliantly simple!  What does the oncoming air see.

@Wyatt No, I'm afraid that "top defelcts more than bottom" theory is wrong. I think interference is lower with positive stagger and positive angle of attack. If you look at efficiency at negative lift coefficients, negative stagger would show better efficiency.

This answer isn't an intuitive explanation of why, just a set of numerical observations that support the claim.
NACA Technical Note no. 70, "The effect of staggering a biplane," by F.H. Norton, 1921.

This investigation was carried out at the MIT wind tunnel in 1918.  ... The lift, drag, and center of pressure travel are determined for a biplane with a stagger varying from +100% to -100%. It is found that the efficiency and the maximum lift increase with positive stagger.

Fig. 4 plots L/D vs. stagger for AoAs from -2 to 18 degrees.  At moderate stagger (-50% vs. +50%), for AoAs from 0 to 10 degrees, L/D improved by 20% to 1%.
(Fig. 2 plots CL vs. stagger, ignoring CD and thus ignoring efficiency.  Especially at AoAs exceeding 10 degrees, CL increases greatly with positive stagger.  This trend may inspire an intuitive explanation.)

Unfortunately this does not answer the question which is why is positive stagger more efficient.

Yes, as stated.  But it might inspire a more targeted answer, and it's too long for a comment.

I've become skittish about "why" questions (elementary "why do foils cause lift" or trickier ones about tip vortices and sweep and downwash) whose answers can validly range from "just navier-stokes it and see" to utter albeit inspiring handwavium.

Still, and answers should at least try to match the question. The document you linked is easily found, yet I decided not to use it as an answer because it does not provide answer to this question. Why staggering does what it does is a very valid question despite its simplicity.
